# File upload using ajax in Struts2

Tags: ajax, file, upload, struts2

i would like to upload a file using ajax and strtus2 without any jquery it should simple upload with ajax and action it should process the multipart/form data and save file in specified path.

Comment: What do you have against jQuery, where presumably any other JS is acceptable?

Comment: I need simple action from ajax to struts2 bean class

Comment: File uploading has been addressed here on SO multiple times.  In short make an action with a setter/getter for a File[] property. On the form you can then create multiple file upload form elements with the same name and they will then transfer the files to the struts action. You must use JS/flash/or the multiple attribute (No IE support) for the browser to perform multifile selection in a nice way. Attributes restricting multifile upload and individual max file size I know are covered here too.